# isolating part of a url with php

Tags: php

If I have the following url:

```
http://URL/products/38/293/bannana_cake/
```

or

```
htp://URL/products/38/293/fruit_cake/
```

How can I isolate just `bannana_cake` and `fruit_cake` from the examples above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';    
print_r(parse_url($url));    
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

And then use `explode()` on the 'path' element. 
For example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://URL/products/38/293/bannana%5Fcake/';
$a = parse_url($url);
$p = explode('/', $a['path']);
echo $p[4];
?>
```

Comment: wouldn't this just isolate everthing to the right of the URL ?

Comment: I added the explode functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way, which only applies to your special case and is not something for production, is to use the [basename-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
<?php
echo basename("http://url/products/38/293/banana_cake/"); // Produces "banana_cake"
?>
```

This only works because "banana_cake" is the last part of the url and there is nothing behind the last slash.

It is definately not a desirable solution and Luca Matteis' answer will get my vote, because the slightest change in the query string order will break things.

Answer (score 0):

it will be a $_GET variable as what you're looking at is just a mod_rewrite version of a query string

try this to see what the variable name is:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_GET);?>
</pre>
```

Comment: not necessarily $_GET, might be in $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] depending on rewrite config

Answer (score 0):

You can see the URL that has been requested by looking at the $_SERVER[] array (Google that to find the exact entry).  They you can split the string into an array on '/', then the [3] index will be the part of the URL you're interested in.

Comment: An example would be nice showing exactly how to slice split the string and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Split the url on the slashes and retrieve the last part:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
echo $parts[sizeof($parts) - 2];
```

Only problem, you need to have the trailing slash in the url. You could make a check for that like this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
echo ($parts[sizeof($parts) - 1])
    ? $parts[sizeof($parts) - 1]
    : $parts[sizeof($parts) - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be slightly longer. It looks like you want to do something similar to using [URI Templates](http://bitworking.org/news/URI_Templates), so here's a snippet of two functions from a class (called xs_Breakdown) I have that does these things. It could easily be extended to include wildcards and conditional behaviour (on the todo list for a time in the future I'm suffering from too little to do). First, and example of setting up and use ;

```
   $br = new xs_Breakdown ( '{first}/{second}/{third}/{fourth}/{fifth}/{andsoon}' ) ;

   // Pick out the template variable called 'third'
   $third = $br->third ;
```

The code (just the basics which should be enough to kick up some of your own dust; all the code would be too long to post here. Pop me a message if you'd like the whole shebang with three nested property / Java Bean-like classes) ;

```
// Static variable to hold our tokens
$_tokens = null ;

// Input path (set in constructor)
$_path = null ;

// Results here
$values = array() ;

function parse ( $schema = '' ) {

            // Sanitize input data : Regular Expression
            $regexp = '/[^a-z0-9 +\-\/!$*_=|.:]/i' ;

            // Break our path into little bits
            $break = explode ( '/', $this->_path ) ;

            // Find the tokens used from our schema template
            $this->_tokens = $this->getSubStrs ( "{","}", $schema ) ;

            // Loop through the path elements
            foreach ( $break as $key => $value ) {

                // Sanitize the value of the element
                $value = urldecode ( trim ( preg_replace ( $regexp, '', $value ) ) ) ;

                // Element not blank? (Meaning, real text)
                if ( $value != '' )

                    // Index it!
                    @$this->values[$this->_tokens[$key]] = $value ;

            }

        }

        function getSubStrs ( $from, $to, $str, &$result = array () ) {

            if ( strpos ( $str, $from ) !== false ) {

                $start = strpos ( $str, $from ) + 1 ;
                $end = strpos ( $str, $to ) - 1 ;

                $item = substr ( $str, $start, $end - $start + 1 ) ;
                $rest = substr ( $str, $end + 2 ) ;

                $result[] = $item ;

                $this->getSubStrs ( $from, $to, $rest, $result ) ;

            }

            return $result ;
        }
```